# AttributeError: can't set attribute,

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have this vgg model. Which I am using to extract an image features. But I am getting an attribute error: I can't seem to understand the error. I am using keras 2.2.4 and tensorflow 1.13.1 with python 3.7.3. I am using anaconda with spyder as IDE.

````
import numpy as np
import warnings


#tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalMaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import layer_utils , get_source_inputs
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
#from keras.engine.topology import get_source_inputs

#from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.layer_utils import get_source_inputs


WEIGHTS_PATH = 'https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5'
WEIGHTS_PATH_NO_TOP = 'https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'

import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

def VGG16(include_top=True, weights='imagenet',
          input_tensor=None, input_shape=None,
          pooling=None,
          classes=1000):

    if weights not in {'imagenet', None}:
        raise ValueError('The `weights` argument should be either '
                         '`None` (random initialization) or `imagenet` '
                         '(pre-training on ImageNet).')

    if weights == 'imagenet' and include_top and classes != 1000:
        raise ValueError('If using `weights` as imagenet with `include_top`'
                         ' as true, `classes` should be 1000')
    # Determine proper input shape
    input_shape = _obtain_input_shape(input_shape,
                                      default_size=224,
                                      min_size=48,
                                      data_format=K.image_data_format(),
                                      require_flatten=include_top)

    if input_tensor is None:
        img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    else:
        if not K.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):
            img_input = Input(tensor=input_tensor, shape=input_shape)
        else:
            img_input = input_tensor
    # Block 1
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv1')(img_input)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv2')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool')(x)

    # Block 2
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv2')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block2_pool')(x)

    # Block 3
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block3_pool')(x)

    # Block 4
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block4_pool')(x)

    # Block 5
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block5_pool')(x)

    if include_top:
        # Classification block
        x = Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
        x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
        x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
        x = Dense(classes, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
    else:
        if pooling == 'avg':
            x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
        elif pooling == 'max':
            x = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)

    # Ensure that the model takes into account
    # any potential predecessors of `input_tensor`.
    if input_tensor is not None:
        inputs = get_source_inputs(input_tensor)
    else:
        inputs = img_input
    # Create model.
    model = Model(inputs, x, name='vgg16')

    # load weights
    if weights == 'imagenet':
        if include_top:
            weights_path = get_file('vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5',
                                    WEIGHTS_PATH,
                                   )
        else:
            weights_path = get_file('vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5',
                                    WEIGHTS_PATH_NO_TOP,
                                    cache_subdir='models')
        model.load_weights(weights_path)
        if K.backend() == 'theano':
            layer_utils.convert_all_kernels_in_model(model)

        if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
            if include_top:
                maxpool = model.get_layer(name='block5_pool')
                shape = maxpool.output_shape[1:]
                dense = model.get_layer(name='fc1')
                layer_utils.convert_dense_weights_data_format(dense, shape, 'channels_first')

            if K.backend() == 'tensorflow':
                warnings.warn('You are using the TensorFlow backend, yet you '
                              'are using the Theano '
                              'image data format convention '
                              '(`image_data_format="channels_first"`). '
                              'For best performance, set '
                              '`image_data_format="channels_last"` in '
                              'your Keras config '
                              'at ~/.keras/keras.json.')
    model.layers.pop() # Get rid of the classification layer
    model.outputs = [model.layers[-1].output]
    model.layers[-1].outbound_nodes = [ ]
    return model```
````

I am getting the following error on the second last line of the code:

````
File "/home/natsu/Final_code/vgg16.py", line 200, in VGG16

    model.layers[-1].outbound_nodes = []

  File "/home/natsu/anaconda3/envs/py-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1639, in __setattr__
    super(Layer, self).__setattr__(name, value)

AttributeError: can't set attribute```
````

Comment: what are you trying to do with this line of code?

Comment: To remove the last classification layer of the VGG model.

Comment: What do you understand from that error message?

Comment: I didn't really understand it much. Thats why i am here for help

Answer (score 1):

I was able to execute your code successfully in tensorflow version 1.15 without any modifications.

I was able to execute your code successfully in tensorflow version 2.2.0 with minor modifications shown below -

Modify,

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import layer_utils , get_source_inputs
```

to

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import layer_utils
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.layer_utils import get_source_inputs
```

Can you please upgrade the tensorflow version and check if the error is fixed.

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Natsu - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.